# Динамический вывод суммы чисел из инпутов JS

Tags: javascript

Есть инпуты:

```
<input type="number" name="sum1" id="sum1">
<input type="number" name="sum2" id="sum2">
<input type="number" name="result" id="result">
```

Как с помощью JS при вводе значений в инпуты sum1 и sum2, автоматически выводить сумму в инпуте result, без нажатия на какие-либо кнопки?

Comment: повесить слушателей на инпуты, в колбэках считать результат. в чём сложность - не ясно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , для человека, который только начинает изучать JS, любая простая задача может быть сложной, а термины вроде "слушатели" или "колбэки" могут быть и вовсе незнакомы

Comment: Так может стоит для начала хотя бы одну книгу прочитать по JS, а только потом что-то делать? В любых книгах для новичков всё это подробно описано.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я сам когда начинал учить JS ничего не мог нормально запомнить (из терминологии), только когда я набрался опыта в практике, только тогда и начал изучать терминологию (и только когда знал практику, смог выучить). Так что сразу новичков на термины сажать не нужно, как по мне, вы как хотите, так и думайте.

Comment: @ΝNL993 при прочтении книги, что-то в голове, да откладывается. И потом если слово проскакивает, невольно понимаешь, что где-то да, читал.... А когда вовсе не читаешь - ты их и не знаешь вовсе, как ТС. Их не надо зубрить к тому же. И не вижу проблем каждую главу немного отработать практически, сделав несколько задач с ними связанных...тогда и в голове всё отложится... А если за 5 минут всё пролистать - не значит выучил... Ну и не читая вовсе тоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как вариант (Если что я `#result` сделал `readonly`):

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input:not(#result)')) {
  e.addEventListener('input', check)

  function check() {
    let result = document.querySelector('#result'),
      sum1 = document.querySelector('#sum1'),
      sum2 = document.querySelector('#sum2'),
      res = +sum1.value + (+sum2.value)

    result.value = res
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="sum1" id="sum1">
<input type="number" name="sum2" id="sum2">
<input type="number" readonly name="result" id="result">
```

Тут добавляем событие `input` на каждый `<input>` который НЕ является `#result`, после, когда пользователь сделает какое-то взаимодействие с инпутом, тогда будет выполнена функция `check`, в которой строки сначала переводятся из типа строк в тип чисел, а после плюсуются и заносятся в `#result`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: @АлександрЗинченко не за что, если вы хотите понять как работает мой код и в принципе подробней изучить JavaScript, то рекомендую к ознакомлению: `Element.value`, `addEventListener` и петли `for...of` / `for...in`, также унарный оператор `+`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 петли?)) Впервые вижу чтобы циклы так обзывали :)

Comment: @EzioMercer по привычке так перевёл с англ. loop -> петля, забыл как правильно :p